# how to check api having requestbody annotation in postman

Tags: api, postman

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createuser", method=RequestMethod.POST,produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody UserMessage createUser(@RequestBody User userObj,final HttpServletResponse response)
```

how to test this controller/api in postman

having POJO for User

Answer (score 0):

http:////create_user

Domain address is the location where your app is running
APPLICATION_NAME = is application base name

[image]